# RJDBC connection unreliable

Tags: r, linux, redhat, rjdbc

I'm trying to run a Rscript in red hat linux server. Rscript connects and sends query to Oracle DB, using the method dbConnect & dbSendQuery, provided by the package "RJDBC". I have tried connecting many times, and failed in the majority of them when the script attempts to call dbConnect method to connect. When I do fail, I get following error:

```
Loading required package: RJDBC 
Loading required package: methods 
Loading required package: DBI 
Loading required package: rJava 
[1] "Driver is created. Establishing Connection" #RJDBC driver called.
Error in .jcall("java/sql/DriverManager", "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "getConnection",  :    
    ignoring SIGPIPE signal 
Calls: dbConnect -> dbConnect -> .local -> .jcall -> .External Execution halted
```

what baffles me is that I have seen instances where the connection did get established, after which the rest of the script runs successfully. What's more, in Rstudio that's installed within the server, the connection is always successful. Only when I run the same script in commandLine do I observe connection failure. I'm really lost as to where I can begin to find what's wrong. Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? Ran into this error today using `Rconnect server`

Comment: it turned out I was dropped from ACL for the time being. sorry for the useless response.

Comment: @SHY_90 can you please elaborate, same exact problem

Comment: @SHY_90 yeah, I have the same problem, and I don't understand your comment